# How does numpy.loadtxt() handle text encoding? (and how is it related to the following error?)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to import data from a text file using `numpy.loadtxt`. This is something I've done many times in the past without issue. However, after generating a new set of text files to import, something about the encoding must be different because I get an error when trying to run the following code:

```
import numpy as np 

asdf = np.loadtxt('data/asdf.txt', skiprows=28, max_rows=720, usecols=range(1,722))
```

The error message I receive is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/iangullett/Desktop/coadd/coadd.py in <module>()
     61 
     62 
---> 63 test = np.loadtxt('data/asdf.txt')
     64 
     65 

/Users/iangullett/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin, encoding, max_rows)
   1091         try:
   1092             while not first_vals:
-> 1093                 first_line = next(fh)
   1094                 first_vals = split_line(first_line)
   1095         except StopIteration:

/Users/iangullett/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc in decode(self, input, final)
    312         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    313         data = self.buffer + input
--> 314         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    315         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    316         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

And for reference, here is a bit of the beginning of the text file I'm trying to read (which is actually very large):

```
Detector Viewer Listing

File : C:\file_path_hidden
Title: 
Date : 10/16/2019


Detector 6, NSCG Surface 1: 
Max polar angle: 90.00 deg, Total Hits = 224724030

Peak Intensity  : 3.957E+005 Watts/Steradian
Total Power     : 9.915E-001 Watts
Data Type       : Radiant Intensity
Maximum Angle   : 90.0000
Detector X      : 0.0000
Detector Y      : 0.0000
Detector Z      : 0.0000
Detector Tilt X : 0.0000
Detector Tilt Y : 180.0000
Detector Tilt Z : 0.0000
Units           : Watts/Steradian

Radial Pixels   : 721, increment 0.1250 degrees
Azimuthal Pixels: 720, increment 0.5000 degrees
Columns are radial angles, rows are azimuthal angles.

Power Values:
                 1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you save the file with utf-16 encoding in notepad by any chance?

Comment: What version of numpy?

Comment: I don't believe so. The text files are from an optical simulation package called Zemax Optics Studio. Nothing happens to them between exporting them (from zemax) and attempting to import them. 

Is there an easy way to check encoding? Or rather, does numpy.loadtxt() expect a certain type of encoding?

Comment: I'm running numpy version 1.16.5

Comment: That should be fine. You need to find out what the output encoding is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) has supported an `encoding` argument since version 1.14.0. It allows you to manually set the encoding. Something like UTF-16 comes to mind as a possibility when the first byte is 0xFF. However the actual determination of the encoding is best made by investigating the program that created your file.

Comment: This was the issue. Adding `encoding='UTF-16'` to the loadtxt() function solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: It's a pretty windows specific problem to have. UTF-16 is such a PITA.